# How to read .csv file row wise using PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to make a PHP script that reads each row of a .csv file. I want to treat each row as an array of data. Please suggest how I can achieve the above?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase that ?

Comment: If you google "read csv row php" the first result is [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: *"I am making a php script"* Really? Because it sounds like you want us to make it for you from scratch. Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
// Read the first line, headers
$headers = fgetcsv($file);
// Now $headers is an array of your headers

// Read the lines one by one
while (false != ($line = fgetcsv($file))) {
    // $line is an array of your cells
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to create an array from the csv;

```
$aArray = str_getcsv ( file_get_contents("/path/to/file.csv") , ',', '"', "\\");
var_dump($aArray);
```

Have a read of the PHP manual;
[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fgetcsv` function to read data from a csv file. Please, look at this :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use following to read row from csv file and create array from the csv file:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("/path/to/file.csv","r");
$arrayCsv = array();
while(!feof($file)) {      
  $fpTotal = fgetcsv($file);
  array_push($arrayCsv,$fpTotal);
}
fclose($file);
print_r($arrayCsv); //prints array from csv
?>
```